# is_uploaded_file() blanks picture file when it is .bmp, why?

Tags: php, upload

When I upload any file everything looks good. I have those pictures in pics folder. The unknown part is when I upload a bmp file. I check file types to see if they are jpg,gif, etc. But code doesn't reach there.
I've also echoed $_FILES['upload'] it was as below:

```
Array
(
    [name] => picture.bmp
    [type] => 
    [tmp_name] => 
    [error] => 1
    [size] => 0
)
```

The code is:

```
if( is_uploaded_file( $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'] ) ) 
{
       // it does not reach here when it is bmp.
}
```

bmp file size is about 2.5MB and upload_max_filesize = 5M in `PHP.ini`. I didn't have this issue before. Is there something here I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 1 [means](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php):

> The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

Perhaps you edited the wrong `php.ini`, or the directive is changed with an `ini_set` later on. To be sure, do a `phpinfo()` right before the upload processing code.

Comment: As I said my picture is 2.5MB and upload_max_filesize = 5M

Comment: See my updated answer, perhaps it gives you more clues where to look.

Answer (score 1):

See php [upload error codes](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

As per php documentation

```
UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
```

Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the [upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) directive in php.ini.